# Run Flow option Missing SharePoint MS flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have created a "For a selected item" flow and i was able to run the flow and test, it all works fine. But the users and not able to see this "Run Flow" option for them to run this flow.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The user must click the **Continue** button, so a connection to SharePoint can be opened. This will only be required the first time the user starts this particular flow. After that, they can just select an item or document and run the flow.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the users to the "Run only users" section in the Flow Details screen

[image: Power Automate Connections/Owners/Run only users - screenshot]